# Too few arguments error

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my code to fill in an array inside a struct with data from a file.

As of right now it's not compiling, just giving the error that's in the title.

I hope to figure this out so I can continue working on the code, but the last 4hrs have done nothing for me...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

FILE *fp;
FILE *fpIn;
FILE *fpOut;

typedef struct {
    char first[7];
    char initial[1];
    char last[9];
    char street[16];
    char city[11];
    char state[2];
    char zip[5];
    int age;
    char sex[1];
    int tenure;
    double salary;
    } workers;

void readFile();
void strsub (char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end);

int main()
{

        if (!(fpIn = fopen("payfile.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("payfile.txt could not be opened for input.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w")))
    {
        printf("csis.txt could not be opened for output.");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

void readFile()
{
    char buf[MAX];
    while(!feof(fpIn))
    {
        fgets(buf, MAX, fpIn);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].first, 0, 6);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].initial, 8, 8);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].last, 10, 18);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].street, 20, 35);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].city, 37, 47);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].state, 49, 50);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].zip, 52, 56);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].age, 58, 59);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].sex, 61, 61);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].tenure, 63, 63);
        strsub(buf, workers[i].salary, 65, 70);
    }
}

void strsub (char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end)
{
    int i, j;

    for (j=0, i=start; i <= end; i++, j++)
    {
        sub[j] = buf[i];
    }
    sub[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the error code is coming from the first strsub function in the readFile funtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed so that your program compiles, but it still has issues. I had to comment out a type mismatch, but at least this compiles so that you have something to work on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

FILE *fp;
FILE *fpIn;
FILE *fpOut;

typedef struct {
    char first[7];
    char initial[1];
    char last[9];
    char street[16];
    char city[11];
    char state[2];
    char zip[5];
    int age;
    char sex[1];
    int tenure;
    double salary;
} workers;

void readFile();
void strsub (char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end);

int main()
{

    if (!(fpIn = fopen("payfile.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("payfile.txt could not be opened for input.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w")))
    {
        printf("csis.txt could not be opened for output.");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
workers array[8];
void readFile()
{
    int i =0;
    char buf[MAX];
    while(!feof(fpIn))
    {
        fgets(buf, MAX, fpIn);
        strsub(buf, array[i].first, 0, 6);
        strsub(buf, array[i].initial, 8, 8);
        strsub(buf, array[i].last, 10, 18);
        strsub(buf, array[i].street, 20, 35);
        strsub(buf, array[i].city, 37, 47);
        strsub(buf, array[i].state, 49, 50);
        strsub(buf, array[i].zip, 52, 56);
        strsub(buf, array[i].age, 58, 59);
        strsub(buf, array[i].sex, 61, 61);
        strsub(buf, array[i].tenure, 63, 63);
        //strsub(buf, array[i].salary, 65, 70);
    }
}

void strsub (char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end)
{
    int i, j;

    for (j=0, i=start; i <= end; i++, j++)
    {
        sub[j] = buf[i];
    }
    sub[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What was the problem in last strsub?

Comment: @Prince In the last line of `strsub`, there is a type mismatch between `double` and `char`. The OP also had not declared the `i` variable and not declared the array, which gave a compilation error.

Comment: Greatly appreciated Programmer 400

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I could read the double into the array?

Comment: @ColeKujawa Maybe if you use a `void *` pointer as an argument, but I didn't try it. It is possible, but we have to strech a little.